# Track Performance of Angular App with Python

Tags: python, performance-analysis, angularjs

I have an angular app for which I wish to track performance metrics. I'm looking for a 'via Python' way to do it.

1. [Pytractor](https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor) - This has sync issues with angular app, as far as I have gone into it.
2. [Protractor-Perf](https://github.com/axemclion/protractor-perf) - This gives exact data and control but is not via python, the test needs to be written in JavaScript (for some reason, I prefer Python)
3. [Perf-Jankie](https://github.com/axemclion/perfjankie) - I know this uses `browser-perf`, and generates a report. But again, this will only plot the data, and not compare and raise/flag a failure.

I've already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596229/browser-performance-tests-through-selenium), but I am pretty sure this will have sync issues with angular app.
Reference: Moved from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722078/track-performance-of-angular-app-with-python), as this was suggested to be more suitable for this network.